# Including dotnetfx into setup project problem

Tags: c#, .net, setup-project

I've included .NET 3.5 prerequisite and chose to download it from the same location as application (second radio button).

And when user runs setup he gets
WinVerifyTrust returned -2146869232 
File not trusted
in log file.

But if he runs dotNetFx35setup.exe (from included DotNetFX35 folder), setup runs fine.

Does anybody know what's the matter?

Comment: Which operating system? At which user level are we executing?

Comment: Virtual PC: WinXP, Windows server 2003 - admin.  Physical machine: Windows XP - user level I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

> This problem may be caused by the
>   version of Windows 98 and Windows ME's
>   Windows Installer is too low. The
>   WinVerifyTrust operation is only 
>   available on Windows Installer version
>   2.0 or later.

http://www.ureader.com/msg/1540740.aspx

Comment: Have you checked it yourself? Well, I've also included Windows Installer 3.1 into prerequisites but I do not know how to setup an installation order of those.